# Issue with Realtek 8811CU installation script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, wifi, driver

I'm new here, so apologies if this is the wrong forum, but I do need to debug this setup script so it seems appropriate enough.

I bought a USB WiFi chip on Amazon (the [Ourlink AC600](https://www.amazon.ca/OURLINK-600mbps-802-11ac-Wireless-10-6-10-12-4/dp/B018TX8IDA/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1536803518&sr=8-5&keywords=ourlink%20ac600)) which uses the Realtek 8811CU chipset and the installation  script it comes with for Linux is giving me errors right off the bat.

I tried more or less to debug but I'm simply awful with shell scripts so I didn't make too much progress. Here's the output of running `chmod +x install.sh && /install.sh`:

```
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
November, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:

tar: Old option 'f' requires an argument.
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.1_22211.20170517_COEX20170310-1212.rar
./install.sh: line 25: cd: 
rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.1_22211.20170517_COEX20170310-1212.rar: Not a 
directory
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

After I figured it was trying to decompress an archive that wasn't there (as the only archive present is a .rar) I edited the script to search for rar files instead (by changing the variable to grep .rar instead of .tar.gz on line 18 and 23). I then changed the tar extraction command to "unrar e" as it was no longer trying to extract a tar ball. When I ran it I got [this output](https://pastebin.com/uZiyD3Zw). Pastebin as it's rather long.

And while I would go ahead and check the error message, the driver package includes no such references. Evidently next time I should buy from a name brand.

Here's pastebins of the contents of [install.sh](https://pastebin.com/h1xZ1Suz) and the respective [Makefile](https://pastebin.com/FZpaHDGA) the script uses, as they seem important. If anyone has any ideas, is in need of more info, or has a working driver for the 8811CU, please let me know! As I'm a total newbie when it comes to debugging driver install scripts, any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

And I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I bought the same thing (Ourlink AC600) from Amazon too two weeks ago. I did not try the Linux driver from the CD because it's dated 2015. I also tried ourlink.us website but the driver download link lead to a dead-end. However, I managed to just install it on my ubuntu box today after some web-digging. Here are my setup/steps:

1. Dell core duo desktop (wired only) with Ubuntu 18.04.1 (up-to-date via: sudo apt-get update)
2. Plugin the AC600, turn on desktop, login.
3. Make sure you have required build package (via: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git)
4. git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au (download with your wired connection. Also, I did this in ~/Downloads dir to keep my home dir clean)
5. cd rtl8812au
6. sudo make (Only see one or two warnings saying that some code will never be executed, ignore them)
7. sudo make install (do this only after the driver is built in step 6)
8. Reboot, unplug your wired network line.
9. Log back in and click upper-right corner down-triangle, click wireless connection and set it up.

My Ubuntu box goes wireless now. That's how I did it. Hope this helps!